# Svn also ws show green check box

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

on all the systems i see that the file and folder icons always show green check box. it does not change to red or yellow or locked icon when others modifies or commit a file. it does only files files opened or modified locally by me. when i commit the file status for other do not change and they have to always update before starting a project. But my experience says that i will update only those files whose icon is non green for other i do not need to update. can someone tell me if this is a problem with the setting in the svn repository or tortoise svn. thanks a ton.

Comment: The status changes to reflect the condition of files in your local working copy. To get changes from the repository, you have to get updates from the repository, and that will update the file status on your system.

Answer (score 1):

The work cycle for Subversion is to do an initial checkout and then work in a loop that goes something like edit -> update -> commit -> edit -> update -> commit -> etc. Because svn is based on developers doing concurrent edits - by default no file locks - an update should always be for all files (in the "branch" in which you're working).

TortoiseSVN uses icons to indicate the current state of files in your local folders - i.e. it reflects the results of the edits you have made.

To compare the state of your local repo with the server using the command line you do:

```
svn status -u
```

To do the same using tortoise choose "Check for modifications" (which will basically show you the same thing as the icons) and then click on the "Check Repository" button.